# Hex color code copied from online appears different while using as main storyboard background in swift?

Tags: xcode, colors, uicolor

I have tried to use this color from web as my storyboard background

Hex color code copied from online appears different while using as main storyboard background in swift?

## 00ABCA

when I paste it in xcode, It displays a various shade in same color, and not the one I have seen online. Why there is a difference?

How do I use the color what I see online by using its Hexcode  ??

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't selected the right color profile. To change the color profile, click the settings icon on the color picker screen (where you entered the hex-value):

[image: color selection image]

Now you should get a menu like this:

[image]

In order to get the exact same color, make sure that the color profile from the website and XCode match. If the website doesn't explicitly says which one they use, I would try 'generic RGB' (or just try them out until you get what you want).